# magento top menu -i'm trying to edit the file with no success

Tags: php, html, css, magento

i'm trying to design the top menu in all the pages of my website on magento,
to do so i need to add a div inside the li tag ,like this - but the div doesn't show, why?

this is the file i'm editing  app/design/default/default/template/page/topmenu.phtml

```
<?php if ($_menu): ?>
<div id="topmenu">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav" class="clearfix">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
        <li class="last"><div id="extra-div-for-design"></div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
   <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be any number of reasons as to why it isn't showing.

First, Magento relies heavily on server-side cacheing for performance.  Try going into the admin portion of Magento and navigating to System > Cache Management.  Once there flush your block HTML ouptut cache and full page caches.

Next, this version of the menu may not be displaying if it is being overwritten somewhere else.  This is due to Magento's layout hierarchy.  Make sure this is the actual block being displayed.

Finally, I will leave you with this, don't make changes in your default templates.  The reason you don't want to do this is those changes will be overwritten when you update Magento down the road.  Consider learning more about Magento's theme hierarchy:

[Magento's Theme Hierarchy - Changes in CEv1.4 and EEv1.8](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

In case you edit app/design/default/default/template/page/topmenu.phtml and your changes are not reflected when previewing, it has been overridden most likely by the template you are using.

So first check which template your website uses; you can determine that by going to System > Configuration and click on section Design;

[image: Design]

In case you have a similar configuration, it means that most likely the default topmenu.phtml has been overridden by: app/design/default/modern/template/page/topmenu.phtml.

In case it doesn't work, go to System > Configuration > Developer. NOTE: switch to any storeview using the dropdown in the upper left and enable Template Hints. Go see your site and see which file has been loaded for the topmenu.

Comment: thank you very much for your help:)you also have the correct answer